# This is not an eggplant

Tags: riddle

It sure is self centered!
I think it's *fast*!
Hot, I say, definitely hot!
It's ***ALIVE!***
You may say that it's kind of angry (but I wouldn't say it to its face).
It's definitely *big*.
Looks like someone rung its bell!
You might be sitting on it...
Sounds like it might be wet.
It's not as big a deal as it used to be.
Maybe it's not even there at all?

> What does this describe?

Hint:

> If I placed these statements into a one-dimensional [Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array), one might refer to the first statement as *arrayName*[0].

Comment: I hope this is related to angry birds :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is describing

> The Solar System
>  Each line refers to a different body in the Solar System.

It sure is self centered!

> Well, the [Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun) is the centre of the solar system.

I think it's fast!

> [Mercury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_(planet)) sure moves quickly, with an orbital period of 88 days - the fastest in the Solar System.

Hot, I say, definitely hot!

> [Venus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus) is HOT. With a mean surface temp of 462C, it's the hottest in the solar system.

It's ALIVE!

> The [Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth) is alive. As yet, no life has been confirmed elsewhere in the solar system.

You may say that it's kind of angry (but I wouldn't say it to its face).

> [Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars) looks red and it's named after the god of war.

It's definitely big.

> [Jupiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter) - the largest of the planets

Looks like someone rung its bell!

> [Saturn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn) has rings

You might be sitting on it...

> [Uranus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranus) - how cheeky!

Sounds like it might be wet.

> [Neptune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neptune) is named after the god of the sea.

It's not as big a deal as it used to be.

> Poor [Pluto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto) - no longer considered a planet

Maybe it's not even there at all?

> [Planet X](http://www.albanydailystar.com/science/according-to-nasa-planet-x9-is-still-theoretical-san-diego-technology-time-15979.html) which is yet to be seen but exists in theory

Comment: This has to be it. Perfect match on all counts.

Comment: And it's definitely not an eggplant.

Comment: What you refer to in your last explanation [was hypothesised to exist, but this was later disproved.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planets_beyond_Neptune#Planet_X)

Comment: I would say that is was not "disproved," check out this [Caltech video](http://www.space.com/31670-planet-nine-solar-system-discovery.html#ooid=xhcmliMDE63k1UzU_uYpv9W9XEuANTZg) from just this year.

Comment: @Gordon K Curious, did my *array* hint do it for you or would you have gotten it without that hint?

Comment: @Chowzen I would have got it without the array hint, as it only made sense after I got it.

Answer (score 4):

A very long longshot (seems like a really good puzzle by the way):

> Earth/The-Earth

It sure is self centred!

> It's like "Hey, look at me, I got an atmosphere that sustains life and stuff!  Want to see how long I can spin?!"

I think it's fast!

> It's all relative but approx. 18.5 miles per sec

Hot, I say, definitely hot!

> Like a microwaved gobstopper, It's hot in the middle.

It's ALIVE!

> With activity!

You may say that it's kind of angry (but I wouldn't say it to its face).

> Global warming maybe?  And you wouldn't stand looking at the face of the earth calling it angry or you'd look a right plonker

It's definitely big.

> I've heard it's even bigger in the US

Looks like someone rung its bell!

> It has craters in it and stuff?

You might be sitting on it...

> But I'm not.  I have a chair.

Sounds like it might be wet.

> 2/3 of it soaked

It's not as big a deal as it used to be.

> "Ug.  Earth go round sun?  Burn scientist!"

Maybe it's not even there at all?

> Ok... What?  Philosophy maybe?

Comment: Not the answer, but +1 for an entertaining response.

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> a/my butt?

It sure is self centered!

> All butts have "centers".

I think it's fast!

> Not sure about this one.

Hot, I say, definitely hot!

> Oh my... Thank you!

It's ALIVE!

> It's a part of he human body, so it's supposed to be alive.

You may say that it's kind of angry (but I wouldn't say it to its face).

> Butts can have their "temper", and you wouldn't talk to their face when they do.

It's definitely big.

> Well, I retract my previous thanks.

Looks like someone rung its bell!

> I won't answer to your insinuations.

You might be sitting on it...

> I am.

Sounds like it might be wet.

> Butts can emit wet-sounding "noises".

It's not as big a deal as it used to be.

> Oh to be young again...

Maybe it's not even there at all?

> How can I be sure it's there when I can't even see it?

Bonus :

> Butts are NOT eggplants.

Comment: "NSFW?" where do you work, a nunnery?

Comment: @Chowzen My answer was ruder at first, but I completelly rewrote it before posting it. I guess the NSFW warning is useless now.

Comment: +1. Let's see if you can get away with it. I hope we are all adults here and you can get away with that.